# Martial art with lots of high kicks

Tags: tae-kwon-do, jump-kick

When I was a kid (6 years old) I trained for a year in tae kwon do. I liked it but my parents didn't want me to continue doing violent sport. At 21, I want to practice martial arts again.

I loved tae kwon do (the jump kicks are crazy) and I was close to start it again, but then I heard about "mugendo". It has the jumps I like, and more movements than tae kwon do.

Do you know another martial art with that high jump kicks?

Comment: I'm sure you must have done a Google search before asking here, [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/martialarts/comments/3eblyl/has_anyone_here_heard_of_the_martial_art_named/) is one of the higher placed links.

Comment: I did, but maybe some personal experience could help me a little more decicion with discipline should i do =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using kicks I will suggest you [Capoeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capoeira). It has a lot of kicks of any kinds, acrobatic kicks and acrobatic moves. See some [videos here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Capoeira).

But inside a martial art you can practice more the moves you want.

Comment: I havent think on capoeira, thank you mate =)